# Dynamically Enable / Disable different adjacent element in HTML using CSS

Tags: css

[image: Image Attached]

In attached image. By default **create button** and **password inputs** will be in disabled state. once verified with email address **create button** got enabled. based on this button I need to enable those two inputs only using CSS.

This is third party login integration so they restricted JS and other technology. It should be achieved using CSS only.

```
<div class="section1">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <label>Email Address</label>
      <input id="email">
      <button type="submit">Send verification code</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>New Password</label>
      <input id="pwd" disabled>
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Confirm Password</label>
      <input id="cnfpwd" disabled>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="section2">
  <button type="submit" **id="create"** disabled>create</button>
  <button type="submit">cancel</button>
</div>

<!-- CSS -->
label{
  width:100%;
  display:block;
}
input{
  display:block;
}
```

Based on **section2** button I need to enable **section1** inputs using css

Comment: Absolutely impossible. First of all, CSS can not select “upwards” in the DOM, and secondly, CSS can not change the disabled state of an element to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

> based on this button I need to enable those two inputs only using CSS.

Absolutely impossible.

---

First of all, CSS can not select “upwards” in the DOM,

and secondly, CSS can not change the disabled state of an element to begin with.